# Efficient way of selecting massive rows and scaling the selection chronologically?

Tags: sql, time, time-series

I have data inserted in a table every 5 minutes, the columns contain a timestamp and the data. I want to select the data based on a given time frame with data being properly omitted for performance and chronological scaling, so that the query returns a max of something like 32.

For example, I have 2 weeks of data, or 4032 records of 5 minute separated entries. I want to select from beginning to end, reducing the resulting set to 32 records but have the record-set scale chronologically so that each entry in the 32 records are as equidistant in time as possible, also leaving the edge records (The beginning and and ending records in the set) unchanged.

I have code that grabs the massive set and scales iterates through them with a calculated skip interval, removing records as needed and performing checks for the edges. I want to know if there's a faster way to do this in the query instead of server code. I'm using MySQL but I'll accept MsSQL answers too.

Thanks.

Comment: How many records are in the table?

Comment: Sounds like you want to sample every nth record in a range where n is (end - start) / 30? There is a mysql example of numbering each row and taking the modulo at http://www.webveteran.com/blog/index.php/web-coding/mysql/mysql-select-every-nth-record/

Comment: Yes I was thinking about grabbing the edges first (first and last), store the pid, bias the first pid to treat it as zero then use the calculated skip variable as a modulo expression in a where clause. Just trying to figure out how to elegantly deal with sets less than the maximum along with the edges.

Comment: If it becomes a problem getting the math right for the edges, you could resort to select start_date UNION modulo set UNION select end_date

Comment: I see a way to do this, but it involves Tally tables and ranking functions (from MSSQL), and it gets foolishly complex very fast (though, being set based, it'd be very fast). Here's hoping someone comes up with a better algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

So something along these lines where the two dates are the input, the 5 minute range and 32 samples in the range:

```
SELECT rownum
  FROM (SELECT @row := @row +1 AS rownum
              ,@sampleRate AS sampleRate
          FROM (SELECT @row := 0
                      ,@sampleRate := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2011-12-01 00:00:00','2011-12-15 00:00:00') / 5 / 32 ) r
              ,clientpc
         ) ranked
WHERE rownum % @sampleRate = 1
```

Comment: A side question, are you moduling against one to include the first result right? Since traditionally I'm use to checking for divisibility and the auto increment fields begin with 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, don't say I didn't warn you (as per the comments section above). This is written for MSSQL; I'm not familiar with MySQL, so I tried to cut down on the uber-proprietary stuff.  This could probably all be done in one large ugly query, but then it'd be even more unintelligible, so I've broken it down into steps.

First, set up some variables:

```
DECLARE
  @Items  real  = 32   -- How many items you wish to display
 ,@From   int = 16000  --  Low range delimiter on your target data set
 ,@Thru   int = 17500  --  High range delimiter on your target data set
 ,@Total  real         --  Used to store how many items are actually in the target range
```

Brief testing has shown that things fail if @Items is less than 2 or greater than some large multiple of @Total.  Error handling, or testing of inputs, is called for.  I use the real data type so that division produces decimal values, not truncated integers; be sure to set these with integer values, or I don't know what happens.

This next bit creates a "Tally" table, or "table of numbers".  It's just a one-column table of ascending integers, starting with 1 and going up to whatever your upper limit is.  Here, I capped it at 256, since 32 appears to be your max.  (This particular code is pretty obtuse, but it can generate millions of rows in disturbingly little time, so I cut-n-paste it whenever I need stuff like this.)

```
CREATE TABLE #Tally (Num  int  not null)

--  "Table of numbers" data generator, as per Itzik Ben-Gan (from multiple sources)
--  Modified to generate 1 through 256
;WITH
  L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1), --2 rows
  L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L0 AS A, L0 AS B),--4 rows
  L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L1 AS A, L1 AS B),--16 rows
  L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM L2 AS A, L2 AS B),--256 rows
  num AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY C) AS N FROM L3)
 insert #Tally (Num)
  select N FROM num
```

Get the number of rows in the target data set:

```
SELECT @Total = count(*)
 from Time
 where TimeId between @From and @Thru
```

Review query, lists the target range in order with the ranking (position, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) within the set.  This would handle duplicate values.  (I based my tests on our generic "Time" table, which looks like most any Time dimension table in any data warehouse.)

```
SELECT
   row_number() over (order by TimeId) Ranking
  ,TimeId
 from Time
 where TimeId between @From and @Thru
```

Another review query.  This returns the set of numbers that identifies the "break points" of your final set.  For example, if you had 30 items and wanted 7, this would produce {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30}; combined with 1, its the seven you want (if I've got the problem straight).

```
SELECT distinct ceiling((Num - 1) * @Total / (@Items - 1)) from #Tally
```

Here's the workhorse, containing the above two queries.  Basically, take everything from the first query where it's rank/position is the same as an identified "break point" in the second query. I tossed in the first item with an OR, as that's way simpler than trying to cram it in mathematically.

```
SELECT xx.Ranking, xx.TimeId
 from (select
          row_number() over (order by TimeId) Ranking
         ,TimeId
        from Time
        where TimeId between @From and @Thru) xx
 where Ranking in (select distinct ceiling((Num - 1) * @Total / (@Items - 1)) from #Tally)
  or Ranking = 1
```

As I said, it's overly complex, and it might not work for some inputs -- but odds are it should run faster than the procedural alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well I came up with this procedure, any cleaning up is appreciated. It works just like I wanted, after doing some blind debugging. The time is stored as UTC timestamps.

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SelectChronoRange`(IN timeBegin BIGINT,
    IN timeEnd BIGINT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE totalAvail, skip, insideResultMax INT;
    SET @maxResults = 64;

    SELECT count(*)
    INTO totalAvail
    FROM `dediwatcherstats`;

    SET insideResultMax:= @maxResults - 2;
    SET skip := CEIL(totalAvail / insideResultMax);
    SET @firstpid = 0;
    SET @lastpid = 0;

    SELECT `pid` INTO @firstpid
    FROM `dediwatcherstats`
    WHERE
        CASE
            WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL AND timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`>=timeBegin AND `Time`<=timeEnd
            WHEN timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`<=timeEnd
            WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`>=timeBegin
            ELSE
                TRUE
        END
    ORDER BY `Time` ASC, `pid` ASC LIMIT 1;

    SELECT `pid` INTO @lastpid
    FROM `dediwatcherstats`
    WHERE
        CASE
            WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL AND timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`>=timeBegin AND `Time`<=timeEnd
            WHEN timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`<=timeEnd
            WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL THEN
                `Time`>=timeBegin
            ELSE
                TRUE
        END
    ORDER BY `Time` DESC, `pid` DESC LIMIT 1;

    SELECT * FROM
    (
        (
            SELECT * FROM `dediwatcherstats`
            WHERE `pid`=@firstpid
        )
    UNION
        (
        SELECT * FROM `dediwatcherstats`
        WHERE
            CASE
                WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL AND timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                    `Time`>=timeBegin AND `Time`<=timeEnd
                WHEN timeEnd IS NOT NULL THEN
                    `Time`<=timeEnd
                WHEN timeBegin IS NOT NULL THEN
                    `Time`>=timeBegin
                ELSE
                    TRUE
            END
            AND `pid` % skip=0
        LIMIT 62
        )
    ) AS notused
    UNION
        SELECT * FROM `dediwatcherstats`
        WHERE `pid`=@lastpid;
END
```

It works on this simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE `dediwatcherstats` (
  `pid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Time` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Data` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I wish the `LIMIT` clause allowed argument variables though. In the code I posted I used a limit of 64 instead of 32 to anyone that may want to use it.